Why am I getting 'Compose Compiler Gradle plugin is required' in Kotlin 1.9 project?
I’m working on an Android project using Kotlin version 1.9.0, and I'm encountering the following error message when trying to build my project:
Starting in Kotlin 2.0, the Compose Compiler Gradle plugin is required when compose is enabled. See the following link for more information: https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/compose-compiler

Here is a snippet of my build.gradle file:
allprojects {
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.18.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.20"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.1.303'
        classpath 'com.huawei.hms.plugin:analytics:5.0.1.300'
        classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.8.0'
    }
}
}

android {
   compileOptions {
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
}

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
    compose = true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.5.14"
}
}

Even though my project is using Kotlin 1.9.0, I still receive the message about the Compose Compiler plugin required for Kotlin 2.0. I have set kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion to "1.5.14" in composeOptions.
Why am I getting this error?

Try changing classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.20" to match your 1.9.0 Kotlin version.

I tried that, still getting the same message :(

Are your views classic XML views or Jetpack compose views?
If you have just classic XML views you can remove the "build feature" compose = true

If your Kotlin version is > 2.0.0 then you are supposed to use the compose Gradle plugin.
You can find the guide that on official documentation here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/compiler
The steps helped me solve the issue!

That doc is useless. I don't have libs.versions.toml file and don't know where it should be.
